# How to respond to changes in fields of object properties in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

In Delphi 7, descend a new component from `TGraphicControl`, and add a `TFont` property, implement the paint method to write some string using the `TFont` property. Install the component.

At design time when you change the `TFont` property using the property dialog, it will be reflected in your component instantaneously. But when you change individual properties of `TFont` like `Color` or `Size`, your component will not be repainted until you hover over it.

How do I correctly handle changes in fields of object properties?

Comment: The control you derive from already has a font property, you just need to publish it. See TSpeedButton for an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign an event handler to the `TFont.OnChange` event. In the handler, `Invalidate()` your control to trigger a repaint.  For example:

```
type
  TMyControl = class(TGraphicControl)
  private
    FMyFont: TFont;
    procedure MyFontChanged(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SetMyFont(Value: TFont);
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property MyFont: TFont read FMyFont write SetMyFont;
  end;
```

```
constructor TMyControl.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FMyFont := TFont.Create;
  FMyFont.OnChange := MyFontChanged;
end;

destructor TMyControl.Destroy;
begin
  FMyFont.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyControl.MyFontChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TMyControl.SetMyFont(Value: TFont);
begin
  FMyFont.Assign(Value);
end;

procedure TMyControl.Paint;
begin
  // use MyFont as needed...
end;
```

Comment: .. or perform a `CM_FONTCHANGED`  to same effect.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: `CM_FONTCHANGED` is used when the main `TControl.Font` property is changed (which has an `OnChange` handler to trigger a repaint of the control). For custom `TFont`-based properties, you have to hook up their `OnChange` event manually, and should not issue `CM_FONTCHANGED`, just trigger a repaint directly.

Comment: @Remy - You have to put a handler for `OnChange`, I didn't say otherwise. In the handler you can perform a `CM_FONTCHANGED` - it will invalidate the control. There's no reason not to isssue a `CM_FONTCHANGED` in the `OnChange` handler, on the contrary it is *better*. Should the implementation of `TControl.CMFontChanged` changes, you won't need to re-adjust. It is also *better* since the message route is inherently override-able - see `TWinControl.CM_FONTCHANGED` for instance.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: `CM_FONTCHANGED` is meant to notify *only* when `TControl.Font` is changed, not when *any other* Font is changed. Descendants may perform additional operations when `TControl.Font` changes that are undesirable when a *different* Font is changed. Case in point, `TWinControl` handles `CM_FONTCHANGED` by issuing `WM_SETFONT` with the latest `TControl.Font.Handle`, and then issues `CM_PARENTFONTCHANGED` to child controls (which causes side effects if their `ParentFont` is true). And `TForm` handles `CM_FONTCHANGED` by updating its `Canvas.Font` with the latest `TControl.Font`.

Comment: @Remy - Where do you make up `CM_FONTCHANGED` is meant to notify only when `TControl.Font` is changed? It is meant to respond to when a control's font changes. The control in the question already has the code for what it takes to adjust to a font change, whether it's `TControl.Font` or not. I don't understand your reasoning, your case-in-point is same with mine. Never mind...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: the fact that all native VCL components and most 3rd party components issue `CM_FONTCHANGED` *only* when `TControl.Font` is changed and not when other Font properties are changed. And just about every descendant that handles `CM_FONTCHANGED` only looks at the latest `TControl.Font` and not at other Fonts. If you want to issue `CM_FONTCHANGED` for custom Font properties in *your* components, that is your choice. That is not its *intended* purpose, and that is not how most VCL developers use it.

Comment: And in my earlier "case in point", it is overkill to issue `WM_SETFONT` and `CM_PARENTFONTCHANGED` when the `TControl.Font` has not actually changed.